# Images on Project Homepage GoogleCode

Tags: google-code

I'm wondering how to put images on the GoogleCode's project homepage. I read the wiki syntax, but I don't know how to integrate that onto the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [**there**](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax), although **very** well hidden in the "links" section (wtf?):

> Plain URLs such as http://www.google.com/ or ftp://ftp.kernel.org/ are
>       automatically made into links.
>
> You can also provide some descriptive text. For example, the following
>       link points to the [http://www.google.com Google home page].
>
> **If your link points to an image, it will get inserted as an image tag
>       into the page:**
>
> http://code.google.com/images/code_sm.png

Comment: Right I saw that, but how can I get it onto the homepage rather than a wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Source>Browse>wiki, on the right side of the screen you are given an option to **Create** or **Upload** a file.

When you upload it, it will appear in your repository.  (Example)

https://code.google.com/p/star-trek-kg/source/browse/wiki/iA1E15e.jpg

However, that won't display the image.  That apparently needs an alternate link syntax, which I figured out just now (by looking at how other picture links were constructed  :D)

This link syntax will parse as a picture on your project home page.  Note the difference from the above link:

https://star-trek-kg.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/iA1E15e.jpg